# Structured PAAS vs Unstructured PAAS

Tags: cloud, paas, cloud-foundry

I came across this [link](https://wikibon.com/cloud-native-application-platforms-structured-and-unstructured/). What is the difference between Structured and Unstructured PAAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An Unstructured PaaS will provide a container orchestrator and a container runtime, but few restrictions on how the platform can operate. It provides the most flexibility in terms of configuration and the ability to run arbitrary workloads, but it lacks governance and consistency, and can be very difficult to scale in organizations.

A Structured PaaS offers many additional services to the container orchestrator. It is geared toward allowing an operations team to define container packaging, OS versioning, user authentication and authorization, self-service provisioning of data services, and default implementations of logging, monitoring, and network security. A Structured Platform will automatically enforce the rules defined by the operations team, and ensure consistency throughout the entire environment. A Structured Platform has fewer requirements for manual configuration (and opportunities for human error), making it much less complex to scale for large workloads.

Comment: Thanks a lot Corby Page! Are there any examples of structured and unstructured PAAS?

Comment: Unstructured PaaS would be using an orchestrator like Kubernetes or AWS Container Service. Structured PaaS would be a holistic platform like Cloud Foundry.